# 2 dynamic ImageViewer in 1 TableViewCell, How do I set up constraints?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout

I want to set 2 image in 1 tablecell.

And Set constraints like this...

[image]

But error msg is

[image]

2 image is not Static !!! Dynamic image.

Is can set width, height constraint each ?

Answer (score 1):

Do those two UIImagesViews have the same height or one can be higher than the other ?

If yes : 
Just set their "Equal Height" properties by Drag&Drop once on the other and select.

[Equal Height constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO5eO.png)

If no :
Try to add the **Vertical Spacing** Constraint of the second one on your UILabel, then set the "*Vertical compression resistance priority*" if needed.

[Vertical spacing constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSxTj.png)

Hope I helped you ... If not try to be more explicit and we will see.